# Can I connect xib object to any viewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I know it is possible to connect an object in a XiB file (i.e button) and connect it to any viewController. I am also able to go to that viewController and programmatically set properties to that object(everything autocompletes fine, it recognizes the object properties) However, when I run the app, the button is unchanged, what gives?

Is there something I'm missing? Is there an additional step that I need to do when using a ViewController that is not the .m file related to the XIB?

Here's part of the code... I don't get any errors!

```
user.default_sales_rep_id = 2;
    if (user.default_sales_rep_id > 0) {
        buttonMask.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
```

Comment: What do you see if you add `NSLog(@"Button is %@", buttonMask);` just before setting the color?

Comment: What method contains the code in your question?

Comment: Phillip, I get "Button is (null)"

Comment: It appeared as if your outlet is not connected to interface's button object.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely setting the properties on the button too early. Since you don't specify in your question where this code is located, it's hard to say but I'd guess if you put your code in `awakeFromNib` it would work.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    //code here
}
```

Any changes to your view that differ from your XIB should be done in this method as it is called after the view is set up from the XIB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you are calling `[[UIButton alloc] init]` before you attempt manipulating it? I assume you have the button already as an `IBOutlet`, but if I recall, if you wish to make custom changes to the button, you must still do this.